# network-restart-command-doesn't-work-in-root-but-works-in-home-directory

Tags: discussion, support, feature-request, bug

I have a question about my Network Engineering Stack Exchange post: [Network restart command doesn't work in root but works in home directory](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/50905/network-restart-command-doesnt-work-in-root-but-works-in-home-directory)

Comment: What is your question about your post?

Comment: Hi ,
I am trying to configure my debian os VM as a router and after few changes I tried to restart my NICs using  /etc/init.d/networking restart in root directory. It says this error bash:/etc/init.d/networking is not a directory But when I try to run the command from the home directory it did.

Comment: You need to ask your question on the correct SE site. I suggested some in a comment on your original question. For a device to be on-topic for [networkengineering.se], the manufacturer must offer optional, paid support.

Answer (score 0):

On the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, it explains a couple of caveats:

> **and meets the following requirements**
>
> - under your direct control (if the network is not under your control you will not likely be able to provide the information required to
>     answer your question);
> - hardware that has a paid support option from the manufacturer (enterprise/provider class products, some small business class
>     devices);